# Different transition for on/off class but same property

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a div that translates itself in with a simple transition:

```
div{
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transition: all .5s;
}

div.active{
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Then, I toggle the class with JS and it works perfectly. This does the following:

```
On --> Slide div down
Off --> Slide div up
```

What I want to do is:

```
On --> Slide div down
Off --> Slide div down again
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: Here's a demo of what it does: https://jsfiddle.net/bwzy89oq/ (click anywhere)

Comment: Could you provide a demo?

Comment: Yes, wait a minute please

Comment: @ovokuro added!

Comment: He wants it to slide down from the top on first click, and on second click, exit down, not back up.

Comment: exactly what @BenPaddock said, I've seen it a lot of times but I can't find it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you need, sort of, but it starts off playing the animation. I'm working on how to logic that out:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  background: black;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  animation: slider2 .5s forwards;
}

div.active {
  animation: slider .5s forwards;
  /*transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
}

@keyframes slider {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}


@keyframes slider2 {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, if you manage to avoid firing the animation the first time it would be amazing!

Comment: Hey! Figured it out, little bit of JS though, just set the opacity to 0 on the div, and on the first click set it back to 1 :D

Comment: Cool. Yeah, using JS is the simple solution. I was looking for a purely-CSS approach, but it's proving tricky.